# Why java.util is accessible from more than one module : <unnamed>, java.base

Tags: java, maven, pom.xml, java-11

I am new to java and working on mutlimodule maven project.
I am trying to upgrade project from java 8  to java 11.
but when i run 'mvn  clean install' i get below error:

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal com.nickwongdev:aspectj-maven-plugin:1.12.6:compile (default) on project module-1: AJC compiler errors:
[ERROR] error at import java.util.Collection;
[ERROR]        ^^^^^^^^

[ERROR] /home/project-name/module-1/apect/classname1.java:22:0::0 The package java.util is accessible from more than one module: <unnamed>, java.base
```

I am unable to figure out why and where is .
i am using sdk version 11.0.16 and apache maven 3.8.6.

Comment: I have my doubts that this plugin supports Java modules because it too old for that...I would try the original ...because that newer https://github.com/mojohaus/aspectj-maven-plugin

Comment: @khmarbaise can you please elaborate . I could not understood properly.

Comment: I have changed the group id of apectj-maven-plugin to `org.codehaus.mojo`(version 1.14.0) but problem is still same. Also it gives a new error [error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73658409/couldnt-find-aspectjrt-jar-on-classpath-in-intellij) . Can you look at problem @khmarbaise

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It solved. The issue was that I was using 'aspectjrt'(1.9.7) as a transitive dependency of 'aspectj-maven-plugin' and this version of 'aspectjrt' was not compatible with java-11. So I changed it to 1.9.2.
And now it's working.

Additionaly I changed there groupId of this plugin to 'org.codehaus.mojo' and used latest version(1.14.0).
[reference](https://www.eclipse.org/aspectj/doc/released/README-192.html)