# couldn't find aspectjrt.jar on classpath in intellij

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea, aspectj

I am working on multi module maven project. I am doing java upgrade from 8 to 11.
I am facing below error when i do 'mvn clean install'.

```
[INFO] --- aspectj-maven-plugin:1.14.0:compile (default) @ module-1 ---
[INFO] Showing AJC message detail for messages of types: [error, warning, fail]
[WARNING] couldn't find aspectjrt.jar on classpath, checked: /usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-amd64/lib/jrt-fs.jar:/home/.m2/repository/org/motechproject/motech-platform-osgi-extender-fragment/0.27.8/motech-platform-osgi-extender-fragment-0.27.8.jar:/home/.m2/repository/javax/servlet/javax.servlet-api/3.1.0/javax.servlet-api-3.1.0.jar:
```

Even though 'aspectjrt-1.9.7.jar' is present in m2 folder(path: '/home/.m2/repository/org/aspectj/aspectjrt/1.9.7').

Here is aspectj-maven-plugin which i am using in every module.

```
<build>
...
<plugins>
...
 <plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                <artifactId>aspectj-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.14.0</version>
                <dependencies>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
                        <artifactId>aspectjrt</artifactId>
                        <version>1.9.7</version>
                    </dependency>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
                        <artifactId>aspectjtools</artifactId>
                        <version>1.9.7</version>
                    </dependency>
<!--                    <dependency>-->
<!--                        <groupId>com.sun</groupId>-->
<!--                        <artifactId>tools</artifactId>-->
<!--                        <version>8</version>-->
<!--                        <scope>system</scope>-->
<!--                        <systemPath>${project.basedir}/pom.xml</systemPath>-->
<!--                    </dependency>-->
                </dependencies>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>compile</goal>
                            <goal>test-compile</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
                <configuration>
                    <source>11</source>
                    <target>11</target>
                    <complianceLevel>11</complianceLevel>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
</plugins>
</build>
```

I could find the cause of this warning.
Please help me.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`aspectjrt`, as the "rt" (runtime) in the name implies, is a runtime library, which is necessary in order to run aspect-enhanced code. Therefore, you need to make it a regular compile dependency in your POM, not configure it as a dependency for the AspectJ Maven Plugin. The latter one has `aspectjtools` as a dependency already, which encapsulates both the compiler and the runtime. But your compiled code still needs this directly under `project → dependencies` on top level in the POM, not nested in `project → build → plugins → plugin → dependencies`.

```xml
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
  <artifactId>aspectjrt</artifactId>
  <version>${aspectj.version}</version>
</dependency>
```

Whatever `${aspectj.version}` might be in your case.

Comment: [@kriegaex](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1082681/kriegaex) You mean to say i should add "aspectjrt" in dependendency management of root pom.xml like  below 
        ```<dependencyManagemnet>
   <dependencies>
 <dependency>
                <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
                <artifactId>aspectjrt</artifactId>
                <version>1.9.7</version>
            </dependency>

        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>
```
and remove "aspectjrt" from aspectj-maven-plugin.

Comment: Read again, please. I did not say `dependencyManagement`. I wrote **exactly** where to add it. Of yourse, you can also add it to the dependency management section in order to manage the version, but then you still need to refer to it (in that case without version number) where I said you should.

Comment: Yes it removed above warning. It stills work if I add "aspectjrt" in 
```project -> dependencyManagement->dependencies```  instead of ```project->dependencies```.
Thanks.

Comment: That can only work, if the dependency has been defined elsewhere in your project, maybe as a transitive dependency. You should not rely on transitive dependencies in a module where you explicitly use a dependency like in this case. It is bad practice. But maybe the dependency has been defined in a parent POM, which might be OK, depending on the circumstances.